# Confidence set for parameter vector in linear regression

Tags: regression

This questions is in reference to equation 3.15 in the book [*Elements of Statistical Learning*](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) by Tibshirani and coll.

I do understand the individual beta confidence interval estimation as provided in equation 3.14, but equation 3.15 just bowls me:

$$\beta|(\hat{\beta} -\beta)^TX^TX(\hat{\beta} -\beta)\leq \sigma ^2\chi ^2$$

What is the idea being expressed here? What is a confidence set? Can we not estimate the intervals of all the betas as per equation 3.14?

Comment: Please make the question self-contained. I do not have access to the book.

Comment: @varty: The book is freely available (legally) at the link provided by the OP. That said, I still agree the question should be made self-contained if for no other reason than that future versions, or even printings, of the text may have different equation numbering.)

Comment: Sorry this is the eqn I am referring to

Comment: $$\beta|(\hat{\beta} -\beta)^TX^TX(\hat{\beta} -\beta)\leq \sigma ^2\chi ^2$$

Comment: here beta_hat are the estimates for beta, and sigma is the variance of the error term. On the right of sigma_square is the chi_square distribution. Please let me know if I wasnt clear.

Comment: @cardinal The book may be freely available but it would be *nice* on the OP's part to take the effort to make the question self-contained to increase the chances of getting an answer. Speaking for myself, I am less inclined to answer a question that requires me to click a link, go to a specific page in that book, understand the context, navigate back to answer the qn etc.

Comment: @varty: I agree. My intent was not to be argumentative, but simply to (kindly) point out that you *did* have access to the book, in case you were interested.

Comment: @bgbgh you can't estimate the confidence set by estimating the confidence intervals individually, because it does not yield any "global" information: just imagine you were measuring something that is actually a ball. With only measurements along axes, you might claim that you were measuring a cube, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

To make things clearer recall that

$$\hat{\beta}\sim N(\beta,\hat{\sigma}^2(X^TX)^{-1}),$$

When you isolate $\beta_j$ you get that

$$\hat{\beta}_j-\beta_j\sim N(0, \sigma^2 v_j)$$

where $v_j$ are the diagonal elements of $(X^TX)^{-1}$. We can write this alternatively as

$$\frac{\hat{\beta}_j-\beta_j}{\sqrt{v_j}}\sim N(0,\sigma),$$

which is the same as

$$\left(\frac{\hat{\beta}_j-\beta_j}{\sqrt{v_j}}\right)^2=
(\hat{\beta}_j-\beta_j)(v_j)^{-1}(\hat{\beta}_j-\beta_j)\sim \sigma^2 \chi_1^2.$$

Note that those $\beta_j$ that satisfy the condition

$$\left(\frac{\hat{\beta}_j-\beta_j}{\sqrt{v_j}}\right)^2\le \sigma^2\chi_{1,1-\alpha}^2$$

fall in the confidence interval described in the equation 3.14. Hence the confidence interval is the set in real line.

Now similarly we get
$$(X^TX)^{1/2}(\hat\beta-\beta)\sim N(0, \sigma^2 I),$$

so

$$(\hat\beta-\beta)^T X^TX(\hat\beta-\beta)\sim \sigma^2\chi_{p+1}^2$$

where $p$ is the number of the regressors. Using the same analogy we can look for vector points $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^{p+1}$ which satisfy the condition

$$(\hat\beta-\beta)^T X^TX(\hat\beta-\beta)\le \sigma^2\chi_{p+1,1-\alpha}^2.$$

For $p=1$ this set will be the interior of the ellipsis.

The confidence set is used since it accounts for interactions between $\beta_i$ and $\beta_j$. Look at the scatter plot of two independent normal variables (which would be the case for orthogonal regressors with the same variance):

[image]

The circular shape is evident. Using the univariate confidence intervals the confidence set would be square, and this graph illustrates that it will actualy estimate the confidence incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response mpiktas. Here are some follow up questions Can you please elaborate on the step in which you were able to show that (betahat-beta)XtX(betahat-beta) has a chi-squared distribution? Also how does one show that for p = 1, we get an ellipse? What ellipse are you talking about? Then is that wrong to build individual tests on the isolated coefficients?

Comment: Like also the equation in the book says that its an "approximate" confidence interval, what makes it approximate. Forgive my ignorance but I wasnt able to see how you got the scatter plot, are you just plotting you independent normally distributed random variables?

Answer (score 3):

To supplement, if $X\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times (p+1)}$ and $\hat\beta$ is the LS estimation for $\beta$ in the linear regression model $Y=X\beta+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$,

$$
\frac{(\hat{\beta}-\beta)^TX^TX(\hat{\beta}-\beta)}{\hat{\sigma}^2}\sim \chi_{p+1}^2
$$
holds asymptotically when $N\to+\infty$. To see this, we first have
\begin{align}
(\hat{\beta}-\beta)^TX^TX(\hat{\beta}-\beta)\sim & \sigma^2\chi^2_{p+1}\quad\mbox{(from $\hat\beta\sim\mathcal{N}(\beta, \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1})$)}\\
(N-p-1)\hat{\sigma}^2\sim & \sigma^2\chi^2_{N-p-1}
\end{align}
which gives
$$
\frac{(\hat{\beta}-\beta)^TX^TX(\hat{\beta}-\beta)}{(p+1)\hat{\sigma}^2}\sim F_{p+1,N-p-1}
$$
On the other hand, one can prove if $S\sim F_{m,n}$, $T=\lim_{n\to+\infty}mS\sim\chi_m^2$ by  directly computing the limit of $mS$'s PDF, with the help of [the relation between gamma function and beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Relation_to_other_functions) and [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Stirling.27s_formula_for_the_gamma_function). With this claim, we have
$$
\frac{(\hat{\beta}-\beta)^TX^TX(\hat{\beta}-\beta)}{\hat{\sigma}^2}\sim \chi_{p+1}^2\quad(N\to+\infty)
$$.

Answer (score 2):

Because (under the assumption made in the text that the errors are Gaussian with mean zero and with variance $\sigma^2$) the vector $\hat\beta-\beta$ is multinormal with mean zero and covariance matrix $(X^T X)^{-1}\sigma^2$, the squared [Mahalanobis Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) of $\hat\beta$ is (by definition)
$$\frac{1}{\sigma^2}(\hat\beta-\beta)^T(X^T X)(\hat\beta-\beta)$$
and as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance#Normal_distributions, that random variable is $\chi^2$ with $p+1$ degrees of freedom where $p+1$ is the number of dimensions in $\beta$. So, $(\hat\beta-\beta)^T(X^T X)(\hat\beta-\beta)$ is distributed like $\sigma^2 \chi_{p+1}^2$. Thus, under the assumptions in the text, there is a concise answer to the original question.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  This reads like a pithy commentary on the existing answers.  Is there some additional point you are trying to make or emphasize?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. The first answer above does not offer an explicit justification for the claim that the random variable in question is distributed like a chi-squared variable. The second makes an asymptotic claim (as n approaches infinity) that is unnecessary; the statement holds even for finite n. I came across the answers today in searching for information about the claim made in the book and felt that an explanation that offered a citation for the central claim would be useful. But, if my answer is unhelpful, I'm happy to remove it. Thanks!

Comment: The differences can be attributed to different assumptions.  For instance, the asymptotic claim *is* necessary when not assuming Gaussian errors.  But your clarifications are appreciated: it would help to include them in your answer, so that people can more easily see what your contribution is.

Comment: I've attempted to clarify the assumptions. (The text in question does explicitly assume Gaussian errors with mean zero and uniform variance, but that is not stated in the original question.) Thanks!